# Shipping observer module breaks payment option

Tags: magento-1.9, module, event-observer, payment-methods

I made an observer module to limit the possible payment options for certain shipping methods. The most notable is to only allow cash payment with an in-store pickup. This is my Observer.php:

```
public function paymentMethodIsActive(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $event           = $observer->getEvent();
    $method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
    $result          = $event->getResult();
    $carriers        = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();

    if ($carriers == 'storepickup' ){
        if($method->getCode() == 'storepayment'){ $result->isAvailable = true; } else { $result->isAvailable = false; }
    }
```

The modules config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_PaymentFilter>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MyCompany_PaymentFilter>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <payment_method_is_active>
                <observers>
                    <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>MyCompany_PaymentFilter_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>paymentMethodIsActive</method>
                    </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                </observers>
            </payment_method_is_active>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

The module itself works fine; it does only show the cash option when instore pickup is chosen. But it 'disables' the option. When I try to finish the checkout it throws the "The requested Payment Method is not available" error.

Whenever I remove the aforementioned if statement, the cash payment option is shown, available and works properly. If I put the if-statement back in the module, it is shown but not active. Why? How? Huh?

Comment: Can you specify, after which action you called your observer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? The Observer is enabled as a module and active on the site?

Comment: can you please also define your code which you write in config.xml for this observer functionality.

Comment: Ah ok! I updated the question with the config.xml :)